# How to fetch Phone number in new Truecaller SDK 3.0.0?

Tags: android, sdk

I implemeneted android Truecaller SDK 3.0.0. I am trying to fetch Phone Number but I am getting only authorization code.

I tried the below code in OnSuccess of Truecaller but got nothing.

val mobile = tcOAuthData.scopesGranted[1]

Result: "mobile"